# Hiding the jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want to render a datepicker on click of a small image, select the date, use the selected date to populate a group of select elements of years, months and days based on the selected date. I figured out the onSelect portion and applying the selected date to the options in the select element.

My problem is the datepicker doesn't close on date selection. It stays there. If i call the hide() method, it hides the image (part of the span element) as well. This is my HTML code:

```
<span id="pickupCalendar"><img src="/images/calendar.png"></img></span>
```

This is the script:

```
$("#pickupCalendar").click(function () {
    $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            //code to fill the other elements with the selected date goes here
            $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker().hide(); //<-- hides the image (span element along with the datepicker)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have an image inside the span? Why are you defining the date picker in its click handler? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Because i understand a datepicker can be attached to a span element. Here's the fiddle where i replace the image with a button. http://jsfiddle.net/Ysxv3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the HTML markup, so it makes it easier to target the elements.

```
<span id="pickupCalendar"></span><button>Button</button>

    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#pickupCalendar").show();
        $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
               //code to fill the other elements with the selected date goes here
               $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker().hide(); 
            }
        });
    });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysxv3/3/)**

Comment: Excellent! I modified your version which didn't create a subsequent datepicker. This is our solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysxv3/4/ Just saw you made the change. Thanks for the direction! :)

Comment: Yes, just adapt the concept to your context! Glad I could help.

Comment: I still wonder as to why the element gets hidden. The "destroy" works similarly.

Comment: You mean the img element? Because it was within your span that you were hiding. If you hide an html element, all elements within it will get hidden as well.

Comment: So by calling the hide() we're calling it on the parent html element which attached the datepicker. Is there a way to assign an id to the datepicker and then hide that alone?

Comment: Well, not if the datepicker element contains an element which you don't want to hide, as far as I know. The hide() function is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`, which "Turns off the display of an element; all descendant elements also have their display turned off." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$("#pickupCalendar").click(function () {
    $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            //code to fill the other elements with the selected date goes here
            $("#pickupCalendar").datepicker().hide(); 
            $("#pickupCalendar img").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Umm that won't work and it doesn't work. Please note the fiddle.